# As per SEO can we use 'CSS Ellipsis' to cut link title?

Tags: seo, css, links

Few anchor URL are very big in my page, So can I use 'CSS Ellipsis' to hide/cut this?

```
text-overflow: ellipsis;
width: 200px;
white-space: nowrap;
overflow: hidden;
```

**Ex Name:**

Institute of Psychiatr..... (Institute of Psychiatry & Human Behavior)

Comment: Personally I'd avoid using both `text-overflow:ellipsis;` and `overflow:hidden;`, it means you can't do more than one at any time without assigning more classes, you can't use `overflow:scroll` or `overflow:visible`, also fonts can be an issue. I recommend using `&hellip;` when required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is nothing wrong with this. Search engines will still be able to access full text for indexing. Of course, make sure you don't cut all the title, because that might be considered as a deceptive hidden link.

**P.S.**: If the links are really too long and you have dozens and dozens of them, consider making the anchor texts smaller, because there is a (remote and small) risk these might be considered as keyword stuffing.